# C++ design around "undefined/invalid" enum C++

Tags: c++, enums, c++03

Let's say I have the following enum.

```
enum VehicleType
{
    CAR,
    PLANE,
    UNDEFINED
};
```

Now in the Vehicle (imagine a simple class having a VehicleType variable); default constructor I must assign some vehicletype to the vehicle. Not knowing what it is, I don't want to call it a car or a plane so I call it undefined.

This creates a burden on the users of the enum since they must consider how to handle the undefined type. If I want to get rid of the UNDEFINED, what are my options in C++03?

I can think of trying to redesign so that the default constructor is not available at all, but due to the big picture this doesn't seem really feasible unfortunately.

EDIT: The issue is a quite a bit more complicated than the question. But the answer is correct for the question so I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a base class called `Vehicle` and sub classes for `Car` and `Plane`. This way you get rid of the enum altogether.

Comment: Thanks, this is in general the way to go. What if I wanted to avoid a large number of classes (there can be hundreds of VehicleTypes)?